# Signature of Young Diagram

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

In paper of K.C. Misra and T. Miwa on crystal base for basic representation of $U_{q}({{sl_n}}(n))$ they have used signature of a Young Diagram.
Question:what is the meaning of signature of a Young Diagram?

Comment: It's not standard terminology.  My guess, having quickly glanced at the paper, is that it refers to the shape (partition) of the Young diagram.